# Image pixelation library, non-square "pixel" shape

Tags: image, image-editing

I've seen a few libraries that pixelate images, some of them even feature non-square shapes such as [The Pixelator's](http://thepixelator.com/) circle and diamond shapes.

I'm looking however to make a particular shape, I want a "pixel" that is **19x27 px**. Essentially, the image would still look pixelated but it would use tallish rectangle shapes as the pixel base.

Are there any libraries out there that do this, if not, what alterations to existing algorithms/functions would I need to make to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

Unless I am not understanding your question, the algorithm you need is quite simple!

Just break your image up into a grid of rectangles the size you want (in this case 19x27). Loop over each section of the grid and take the average color of the pixels inside (you can simply take the average of each channel in RGB independently). Then set all of the pixels contained inside to the average color.

This would give you an image that is the same size as your input. You could of course resize your image first to a more appropriate output size.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look up convolution matrices.

In a shader, you would use your current pixel location to grab a set of nearby pixels from the original image to render to a pixel in a new buffer image.

It is actually just a slight variation of the Box Blur image processing algorithm except that instead of grabbing from the nearby pixels you would grab by the divisions of the original image relative to the 19x27 divisions of the resulting image.